# How come the netflow data isn't showing up on the server?

Tags: cacti, mikrotik, netflow

I have a mikrotik router and it is sending trafficflow (fully compatible with netflow) data to my debian server that is running cacti.  But after installing cacti's `flowviewer` plugin, cacti doesnt show any information.

The directory I made on the server to hold the netflow data is empty. (I assume this is the problem.) The permissions on that directory are 777.

There was no iptable rule blocking port 2055 but just in case I set:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 2055 -j ACCEPT
```

`tcpdump udp port 2055` shows a lot of data coming in.

The time between the router and the server may possibly be a few seconds apart.

I've stopped and started the flow-capture service in between each change.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you see any flow packets being sent? That will split the problem space in half.

Comment: hm, i thought thats what i was seeing via tcpdump. is that not the case?

Comment: Take a look closely at them. If they look valid, then check the logs of whatever is supposed to collect the data from them. (flow-capture, I assume.)

Comment: the tcpdump info looks good, its all coming from the mikrotik and looks like legit info.  not sure what flow-capture is but it seems to be on my server.  i'l look into it

Comment: Its working!  I guess I didnt have flow-capture running.  I didnt see flow-capture mentioned in any of the tut's I read and didnt know what it is.  its an important part apparently.  Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something has to be listening for those UDP packets! Otherwise, they're just dropped on the floor.